# change a value by a probability value in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to change a variable by probability value,
as a example  I have [ 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 ] in matlab and with **probability = 0.01** change any elemet of it , how can I achive this  in matlab?
(I want use this in GA and with p =0.01 do mutation of Gen of choromosome )
appreciate any help

Comment: Does the probability 0.01 determine *which* element needs to be changed or *when* a random element in your vector needs to be changed?

Comment: 0.01 is probability of each binary element change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, identify all the elements you want to change

```
array = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1];
sizArray = size(array);
probability = 0.01;

toChangeIdx = rand(sizArray) < probability;
```

Then, you can flip zeros and ones where needed

```
array(toChangeIdx) = 1-array(toChangeIdx);
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant condition for your code is

```
if rand() < probability
   % Flip your bit here, e.g. 
   % bitToFlip = randi(length(genome));
   % genome(bitToFlip) = 1 - genome(bitToFlip);
end
```

This will run the code inside the `if` statement with a probability of exactly `probability`.

Comment: Note that Jonas has the simpler answer if you want to change EVERY bit with probability `probability`.